# what is better Amazon EBS or S3 for streaming and uploading video

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

What is better to use, EC2 instances for EBS or Amazon S3 for subscription based streaming channel like Netflix.
150GB upload per month, 250GB streaming per month, no peak time, with viewers based around Australia, India, North America, Europe, Brazil
and 80TB of storage that needs to migrate to the cloud?

Comment: Netflix have already published lots about how they do things. Have you looked into their stuff?

Answer (score 1):

For scalability and worldwide presence, the definite answer (using only AWS services) is:

- Store videos on Amazon S3
- Serve videos through Amazon CloudFront

Amazon CloudFront has presence in 70+ locations around the world and will handle the video streaming protocols for you. Mark content as private and have your application determine whether users are entitled to view videos. You can then generate pre-signed URLs that permit access to a given video for a limited period of time. See: [Serving Private Content through CloudFront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html)

In comparison, using Amazon EC2 + Amazon EBS is a poor choice because:

- You would need to scale-out additional instances based upon your load
- You would need to run instances in multiple regions to be closer to your users (hence lower latency)
- You would need to replicate all videos to every server rather than storing a single copy of each video

Please note that your largest cost will be Data Transfer (see [Amazon CloudFront Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/). Your quoted figure of "250GB streaming per month" seems extremely low -- my family alone uses that much bandwidth per month!

Comment: thanks for the response, would you just use CloudFront, or could you use Lambda if you want to scale up and down, or add subscribers?

Comment: Amazon CloudFront can serve static content, but it cannot run your application code. You will need compute, either from Amazon EC2 or AWS Lambda. Writing [serverless code](https://serverlesscode.com/post/david-guetta-online-recording-with-lambda/) is different to writing code on normal servers and would take some research to get it right.

Comment: thanks again John, so running say an EC2 instance through CloudFront like General Purpose M4x10Large to take the requests and scale up and down, would that work, and do you need to create an AMI for that instance as well for EC2

Comment: You would certainly use Amazon EC2 to run your application, but offload serving of videos to S3 + CloudFront. That will lighten the load on your application so that it is merely generating the HTML pages and interacting with users rather than serving static content (eg videos). How you configure those instances to run your application is totally up to you.

Comment: I decided for example Wowza Streaming engine for the AMI and EC2 instance, but it says EBS storage only, https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/fulfillment?productId=668790f8-598f-42d3-ad55-a2670072241b&ref_=dtl_psb_continue&region=eu-west-1 , it seems all instance types are using EBS storage, but if want to serve the content from S3+Cloudfront, is there a way of integrating the S3 storage instead of an EBS ?

Comment: If you are serving video content from an Amazon EC2 instance (eg with Wowza), then the instance will use EBS storage. I'm not familiar with the engine, so it might allow content to be stored on S3 but the instance itself will use EBS as the boot disk, for storing software, etc. However, wowza might not be compatible with the suggested S3 + CloudFront method. You'll have to do research on the topic.

Comment: Thanks for all advice John, when calculating the TCO for AWS, I know for storage, but do you know what I would put for the following for Servers Sections, No of VM,CPU Cores, VM Usage %, Memory GB, Optimized by RAM, CPU or Storage IO, wont be using much 400GB bandwidth per month, 150GB input, 250GB output, storage 80TB

Comment: Please create a new Question if you wish to ask something different from the original question.